# how to store the data from input fields inside an associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an associative array consist of 4 records. there is 2 input fields called `name` and `grade`. i want to add these records inside the associative array like `name=>grade`. here is what i did but it does not work.

```
$grades = array("Jim"=>"A+","Pam"=>"B","Kevin"=>"Fail","Oscar"=>"A");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$length = count($grades);

for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
    $grades = array($name => $grade);       
}

echo $_POST['name'];
```

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, what's in `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['grade']`? What is your expected output? Now you're replacing an array 4 times and echoing something that is not your array.

Comment: Please see the picture that i post earlier. the above text box which says "query here" is responsible for showing whats inside of associative array. we provide the name of student and it show us the grade of that student....the other 2 text boxes is used to enter records like name and grade inside the associative array... it is like store and retrive from the same associative array. hope you now understand.. please solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the `for()` loop at all? There's no need to loop over the `$grades` array, since you're always explicitly setting a single key/value pair.

`$name` should be the new key, and `$grade` the new value, so the following should suffice:

```
$grades = ["Jim" => "A+", "Pam" => "B", "Kevin" => "Fail", "Oscar" => "A" ];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];

$grades[$name] = $grade;
```

Comment: ah ya mofo beat me to it

Comment: Your previous answer was faulty

Comment: @ZainFarooq Sorry?

Comment: Just in case, OP is (I think? really unclear) looking to **add** grades, not overwrite them.

Comment: @Loek which is what the answer will do, unless `$name` contains a key already defined in `$grades`, in which case they shouldn't be using an array anyway, since keys must be unique...

Comment: @ZainFarooq Actually, it behaved the same, but the `for()` loop was extraneous.

Comment: You were looping it through `for()` without puting `$i` in loop values, in that case it was just overriding the array values each time

Comment: @ZainFarooq There is no need to use `$i`, since `$grades` is an associative array, not a 0-indexed one... Anyway, I'm not entirely sure why you felt the need to point out an outdated edit was faulty, since it was edited to provide an accurate answer?

Comment: btw you can refer to `for()` in @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs answer. In that case values wont be overrided

Comment: @ZainFarooq Yes, I know. But that produces completely different output.

Comment: @ZainFarooq BenM is correct - my answer was just a copy of OP code with edit on how to make it "correct" . this is a preferred way to do

Comment: it does not work? what records i added though input feild must be store after my records that i added manually, & please also mention how can i view inside the associative array with a input feild and a buuton